# Validating user input to see if in range of numbers, if not loop back to ask for user input again

Tags: python, loops

If the player types in any out of range or invalid values, I want it to loop back to ask him to place his bet again.

I can get this half-way working when I wrap raw_input with int().

However, if say the player accidentally typed a letter or just hit enter without typing anything, it would throw an error, thus stopping the game/script.

So if a player does make a mistake like that, I need it to loop back to "Place your bet" again instead of throwing an error and crashing the script.

```
def betAmount():
    if number_of_hands == 1:
        if chip_count_player1 > 0:
            global chips_bet
            chips_bet = raw_input("Place your bet!")
            if chips_bet in range(0, chip_count_player1 + 1):
                print "Your bet is within range"
            else:
                print "NOT IN RANGE"
                betAmount()
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540274/most-pythonic-way-to-do-input-validation/20540530#20540530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to convert the `chips_bet` to a number like this

   ```
   try:
       chips_bet = int(raw_input("Place your bet!"))
   except ValueError:
       betAmount()
   ```
2. You are constructing a new list of numbers and then checking if the `chips_bet` is there in it or not. That is inefficient. You can check like this

   ```
   if 0 <= chips_bet <= chip_count_player1:
   ```
3. The base idea can be implemented like this

   ```
   bet = getBet()
   ...
   def getBet(maximum):
       bet = -1
       while (bet < 0) or (bet > maximum):
           try:
               bet = int(raw_input("Place your bet!"))
           except ValueError: pass
       return bet
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can split your prompt/input/validate loop into a little function, and just call that (it's easier to separate the retry loop from the program logic)

For example, this won't throw, and will only return a validated number:

```
def safe_int_input(prompt, validate):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(raw_input(prompt))
            if validate(val):
                return val
        except: pass
        print "invalid input"
```

and you'd call it like this:

```
chips_bet = safe_int_input("Place your bet! ",
                          lambda v:(v >= 0 and v <= chip_count_player1))
```